# Using Async/Await in Express Handler function throws Typescript error

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have this Express `Handler` function that returns Promise

```
import { Handler } from 'express'

export const fooHandler: Handler = async (_req, res) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  res.send('');
};
```

This however triggers this ESLint error

`Promise-returning function provided to variable where a void return was expected (eslint@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises)`

The weird thing is, this actually works in my older project. Was this rule recently added to ESLint?

Comment: What version of `express` and `@types/express` do you use?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski `"@types/express": "^4.17.13"` and `"express": "^4.18.2"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use async IIFE like this.

```
export const fooHandler: Handler = (_req, res) => {

     (async () => {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
         // rest code
      })();
    };
```

This means that the return value of the callback remains undefined, rather than being a promise.

Comment: This will work, but it seems more like a workaround than a solution